# Optimize multiple processes run TensorFlow on CPU, to use CPU cores 100%?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, tensorflow, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run multiple processes on a machine that has many CPU cores and an enough amount of RAM (250GB).

Each process builds a TensorFlow graph and calls `session.run()` frequently inside a function passed to `scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b()` calls. It's not a very heavy computation (calculation of outputs and gradients of a single-layer neural network for now, and runs even faster on CPU, as I tested).

The problem is, if I run multiple instances of that, `session.run()` calls become too slow.

For comparison, I wrote numpy code that does the same thing for this specific case of a single-layer neural network (while the TF version handles general cases). The result is that, of course the numpy version is faster, but it scales way better too. For instance, 15 processes of the numpy version are still pretty fast, while the same number of processes of the TF version become very slow.

- Environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` is set to `''` for those processes.
- I tried using `tf.ConfigProto` when creating `tf.Session` (e.g. setting `device_count` to limit the number of cores each process uses, and setting `inter_op_parallelism_threads` and `intra_op_parallelism_threads`), but it wasn't effective.
- Using `tf.device()` didn't work, too.
- I even applied tricks introduced [here](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/blob/master/tiny_runs/tiny_tf.py) (calling `TF_Run()` directly, using target list instead of fetch list if possible, and XLA), which didn't help them on a matter of scaling.

I would have given up if CPU or RAM usages were like 90%, but they TOTALLY AREN'T! There is still 150GB of free RAM, and **most of the CPU cores' usages are around 10%**.

How can I make them, at least, **use all the CPU cores efficiently**?

Could someone help me to find out what I did wrong, please?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you'll get the best results if you can aggregate your many small computations into a single batch and run the full batch through. I have been pretty unsuccessful at getting tensorflow to keep my high end GPUs busy when I train models using a batch size of 1 (too many small operations), but it does a good job keeping the GPUs saturated with larger batches. The BLAS and other libraries are well tuned to get the most out of large matrix operations. Not so much if you do many small operations.

Comment: @David Parks Thanks for the comment! Maybe I could try finding a way to gather inputs and process them at once later, and see if things get better, but I still want to make CPU usages high. :) (possibly in this case)